# Deleting a string inside of a struct in C

Tags: c, string, structure

So, I'm trying to delete the content of a string inside of a struct.

i.e:

```
typedef struct data_player{

char name[25];
...
}player

player player_list[10]
```

And for example I want to delete the content of `player_list[1].name`

I tried `player_list[1].name = ""`, but that didn't seem to work, any tips?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

To "erase" a C string it is sufficient to set its initial character to `'\0'`:

```
player_list[1].name[0] = '\0';
```

The rest of the string content would remain there, but all standard functions working with C strings will safely ignore it.

Comment: I tried this but there was this warning:
|warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]|

Comment: @Zetsuno Are you sure you did what's shown above, as opposed to `player_list[1].name = '\0';` which would indeed trigger this warning?

Comment: Oh my god, I'm so sorry, I tried this indeed, exept I was using " instead of ', therefore the warning, which is gone now. Sorry 'bout that

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
memset(player_list[1].name, 0, sizeof(player_list[1].name));
```

This will set all the elements of array `player_list[1].name` to `\0`.

This will also work

```
strcpy(player_list[1].name, "\0");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to "delete" the content of a string you can put `\0` like this:

```
player_list[1].name[0] = '\0';
```